# How can I change this code to not use the lambda function?

Tags: python, lambda

```
import csv                         #working with csv files
from datetime import datetime      #this will allow accessing time for later use

#initialize class for every output
class InventoryReports:
    def __init__(self, item_list):
        self.item_list = item_list      #provide list to create new file


    #Part a
    #Create FullInventory.csv for entire inventory
    #Following order ID, manufacture name, item type, price, service date, damaged
    def fullInventory(self):
        with open('FullInventory.csv', 'w') as file:
            items = self.item_list
            keys = sorted(items.keys(), key=lambda x: items[x]['manufacturer'])              #sorted alphabetically by manufacture
            for item in keys:
                id = item
                manufacture = items[item]['manufacturer']
                itemType = items[item]['item_type']
                price = items[item]['price']
                serviceDate = items[item]['service_date']
                damaged = items[item]['damaged']
                file.write('{},{},{},{},{},{}\n'.format(id, manufacture, itemType, price, serviceDate, damaged))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very verbose method, untested.

```
import csv                         #working with csv files
from datetime import datetime      #this will allow accessing time for later use

#initialize class for every output
class InventoryReports:
    def __init__(self, item_list):
        self.item_list = item_list      #provide list to create new file

    def fullInventory(self):
        with open('FullInventory.csv', 'w') as file:
            items = self.item_list     
            for i in range(len(items)):
                for j in range(len(items) - 1):
                    if items[j][2] > items[j+1][2]:
                        items[j], items[j+1] = items[j+1], items[j]
            for i in range(len(items)):
                for j in range(len(items) - 1):
                    if items[j][1] > items[j+1][1]:
                        items[j], items[j+1] = items[j+1], items[j]
            for i in range(len(items)):
                for j in range(len(items) - 1):
                    if items[j][3] > items[j+1][3]:
                        items[j], items[j+1] = items[j+1], items[j]
            # write header
            file.write('ID,Manufacturer,Item Type,Price,Service Date,Damage\n')
            # write items
            for item in items:
                for i in range(len(item)):
                    if i == 0:
                        file.write(item[i])
                    else:
                        file.write(',' + item[i])
                file.write('\n')
                id = item
                manufacture = items[item]['manufacturer']
                itemType = items[item]['item_type']
                price = items[item]['price']
                serviceDate = items[item]['service_date']
                damaged = items[item]['damaged']
                file.write('{},{},{},{},{},{}\n'.format(id, manufacture, itemType, price, serviceDate, damaged))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
from operator import itemgetter


for item in sorted(items, key=itemgetter('manufacturer')):
    ....
```